# Which Class Lib for ASP.NET Core tag helpers when .Net Core Web App targets Full .Net Framework?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have created a Asp.Net Core Web Application that targets the full .Net Framework. This was accomplished by using the Visual Studio **ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) template.**

I'd like to create some tag helpers that I use in this Web Application and I'd like to place them in a library dll.  Initially I tried adding a new project to my solution of type  **Class Library (.NET Core)** to place them in but I was unable to reference that library from the web project.  When I tried to reference it via Visual Studio I received a dialog that said the project reference was not supported because the Class Library has a target framework that is incompatible with the targets in my Website Project.

So as an alternative, I added a regular **Class Library** project to the solution via the Visual Studio Class Library template.  I am able to add a reference from my Web Project to this class library successfully.  However, in this Class Library project I can't find a way to reference `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime` which is necessary if I'm going to be able to put my tag helpers in the library.

So I'm at a dead end with both approaches.  How can I put my ASP.NET Core tag helpers in a class library that I can reference from my ASP.NET Web Project that targets the full .net framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I tried to reference it via Visual Studio I received a dialog that said the project reference was not supported because the Class Library has a target framework that is incompatible with the targets in my Website Project.

This usually means you both libraries target different things, i.e. if your Class library targets `netstandard1.6` and your web application targets `net452` its not going to work.

Either your web application needs to target `netcoreapp1.0` or your class library has to target `netstandard1.0`. Use the [.NET Standard Library matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) here to see which `netstandard1.x` moniker supports which platform.

So if your web application targets net452, you have to target `netstandard1.0`, `netstandard1.1` or `netstandard1.2`. `netstandard1.3` and higher don't work, because it requires .NET Framework 4.6.

If you use a library which requires `netstandard1.3` or higher, you have to target multiple platforms. i.e. `net452` and `netstandard1.3`.

Then `net452` will be used in projects which target `net452` and `netstandard1.3` will be used in `netcoreapp1.0` applications or other class libraries which target netstandard.

Comment: I can't thank you enough.  That's exactly what I was doing wrong.  My web app was targeting `net452` and my class library was targeting `netstandard1.6`.  Once I changed my class library to targeting `netstandard1.0` it worked.  It also worked when I bumped it to `netstandard1.1`  Thank you!  And thank you for link to the .Net Standard Library matrix.  This netstandard stuff is still pretty confusing but I'm starting to get it with your help!

Comment: Tseng - one other question if my library targets netstandard1.1 how can I have it reference a library that targets net4.5?  From the chart it looks like this should be possible but when I try I get the dialog about the two target frameworks being incompatible.

Comment: @RonC: You can't, because it's not guaranteed that the net 4.5 library may use APIs which are unavailable to .NET Core or other platforms covered by the .NET Standard. The .NET Standard sets the minimum set of APIs supported by the platforms listed in the matrix. In this case you'll need to do multi-targeting (target net45 and netstandard1.1) and use #if precompiler directives to ensure API which only works in full .NET framework won't be compiled into netstandard version of the library

Comment: However, in .NET Standard 2.0 there will be a breaking change, kind of. Netstandard 1.5 and 1.6 won't be compatible anymore as some API which is only available in .NET 4.6.2 and the unreleased .NET 4.6.3  will be removed from netstandard 2.0, but more APIs from .NET 4.x will be added to netstandard. See this MSDN Blog post for more details of the upcoming netstandard 2.0 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/ (however apis available in 1.5 and 1.6 may will be available in  netstandard 2.1 though)